# How many times is Jar Jar killed in Lego Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, lego, jar-jar-binks, lego-star-wars

A common trope in the *Lego Star Wars* shorts is to kill off Jar Jar Binks. How many times does this happen though?

**How many times is Jar Jar Binks killed/destroyed in Lego Star Wars?**

<sub>To avoid making this too broad, I'm only looking at the 22 minute TV shorts. (Currently consisting of "Padawan Menace", "Empire Strikes Out", "Yoda Chronicles", and "Droid Tales").</sub>

Comment: Whatever the numerical answer turns out to be, the true answer is ***"not enough"***

Comment: @Richard I'd bet a sizable sum of Republic credits that "not enough" was _everbody's_ first reaction!

Comment: @JaneS Well... I don't know. For me it's like dog peeing on a hydrant. Nothing to be done about it - it's dog's nature. Ignore it. Which means for me, personally, that I blank out on all his appearances. ;) Selective hearing and selective vision superpowers, picked up quickly after I got married ;)

Comment: @JaneS Not everybody. Some of us actually quite like Jar Jar, believe it or not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Put me in the "or not" category :)  Saying you like Jar Jar is like saying you enjoy toothaches! ;)

Comment: @JaneS No, I'm not very fond of those. I do rather like Jar Jar, though. He is certainly a lot less annoying than Chewie and the bloody Ewoks to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm with you on the Ewoks, but _Chewbacca_? :O

Comment: @JaneS Absolutely. By far the most annoying character in the whole heptalogy.

Comment: **LEGO doesn't *kill*** characters, it's against their internal corporate guidelines for media depictions (I've read them) . They can be destroyed (bricks separated), but it's not a permanent death. At least not on screen.

Comment: @CreationEdge edited question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Surprisingly few times. Just thrice, in fact.

Once in The Padawan Menace, and twice in the first episode of the Droid Tales.

---

**The Padawan Menace:** 1

[image]

**Droid Tales #1: Exit from Endor**: 2

[image]

[image]

**The Empire Strikes Out:** 0

**The Yoda Chronicles: (all 7 episodes)** 0

**[Bombad Bounty](http://legostarwars.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_Bombad_Bounty):** 0

[**The Quest for R2-D2:**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoC13zN1zeE) 0

Comment: Killing Jar Jar seems pretty rare, but they do play with the trope of "*Jar Jar being written out of the shows after a surprisingly brief cameo*" (often just a few seconds) rather more often.

Comment: Has this changed at all in the past year?