# Does anyone die in Lego Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, lego-star-wars

Prompted by [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117475/how-many-times-is-jar-jar-killed-in-lego-star-wars/117529#comment287468_117475) from @CreationEdge...

> **LEGO doesn't *kill* characters**, it's against their internal corporate
>   guidelines for media depictions (I've read them) . They can be
>   destroyed (bricks separated), but it's not a permanent death. At least
>   not on screen.

Are there any instances where a character is **unambiguously killed on-screen** in a Lego Star Wars property?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From a certain point of view, Lego characters die in Lego Star Wars, actually the same that die in the movies.

For instance, here is a video of the last level of Episode I in Lego Star Wars video game. Qui-Gon Jinn is killed by Darth Maul (at 10:00 in the video) and then dies at the end (at 10:35). For me it looks pretty obvious.

Comment: There is also Padmé's death at the end of Episode III, with the same type of death as Qui-Gon ("X"" on the eyes).

Comment: In fairness he makes cameos in future episodes of the game, but only as a force ghost. Padmé doesn't.

Comment: Eyes turn to double X's = death in my book.

Comment: I can actually see how these cases fit within their guidelines, and I'm sure there's some exceptions for retelling the licensed story. But yeah, as you say, from a certain point of view. Then again, did LEGO kill them or did George Lucas?

Answer (score 1):

Also, in the new "Force Awakens" game the fate of Han Solo is the same as in the movie. We only see him falling down the chute, though - so it's not unambiguous as such.